# Selecting highlighted text in preview

Tags: pdf, preview

When I select highlighted text in Preview, I am unable to copy and paste it. If I try to paste it into a text editor, I hear the system alert sound and nothing happens. If I begin my selection just before or after the highlighted passage, then text selection and copying works as normal. Is there any way of copying highlighted text in Preview?

I am using Mojave 10.14.6 and my version of Preview is Version 10.1 (944.6.16.1).

Comment: When you say highlighted text do you mean text that you yourself highlighted or something else. In Preview there is a highlight option.

Comment: Yes, I mean text that I have myself highlighted.

Comment: I'm running High Sierra and Preview 10.0 and the copy and paste of highlighted text works fine. I highlighted a line of text in a PDF file. then I copied it and pasted it into TextEdit